# R: Removing hour,min,sec from date

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I have a data frame contain one date column it is in POSIXCT format as shown below

```
"2019-02-18 00:00:31 IST"
```

I want date in below format

```
 "2019-02-18"
```

but when i applied

```
 x = as.Date( DATE ,"%Y%m%d")
```

it is giving below warning

```
Warning message:
In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz = tz) : unknown timezone '%Y%m%d'
```

And i am getting below wrong( one day previous date) output

```
"2019-02-17"
```

Plz let me know whats going wrong.

Comment: i want to try with out using lubridate

Comment: See the other dupe targets. This has been asked a lot.

Comment: No need to specify any format in this case. Just do `as.Date("2019-02-18 00:00:31 IST")`

Comment: @RonakShah it will convert to previous day

Comment: then it's your system locale issue. You are in a different timezone than the one provided in the string.

Comment: You just pass the time zone within `as.Date()` this should work:

`as.POSIXct("2019-02-18 00:00:31 IST") %>% as.Date(tz = 'Asia/Kolkata')`

Comment: @DS_UNI:  it will generate problem if i get record of different time zone

Comment: True, I assumed that all records have the same time zone, in that case I guess your best option would be the answer by RLave,  using `strftime()` or `formrat()` and then `as.Date()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this also with `strftime()`:

```
strftime(d, format="%Y-%m-%d")
[1] "2019-02-18"
```

With `format=` you can basically choose what you want to extract. It works even with just `"%Y"` in order to extract the year component.

Data:

```
d <- as.POSIXlt("2019-02-18 00:00:31 IST")
```

Comment: it is converting date to character format

Comment: `as.POSIXct()` or `as.Date()` will give you the date format back.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to just cast the POSIXct datetime to a character, and then take the first 10 characters:

```
date <- as.POSIXct("2019-02-18 00:00:31", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz="Asia/Kolkata")
date
date.str <- as.character(date)
substr(date.str, 1, 10)

[1] "2019-02-18 00:00:31 IST"
[1] "2019-02-18"
```